# LINQ and Static ObservableCollection

Tags: vb.net, linq, observablecollection

This will probably be a basic questions for the LINQ & architecture experts however I am failing to understand a problem i've encounted when trying to update a 'Static ObservableCollection.

```
 Me.Grid1.ItemsSource = ContactList

 Me.Grid2.ItemsSource = From s In ContactList Where s.ContactTypes.Any(Function(t) t.ContactTypeName = "Christmas List")
```

If I add a new **Contact** with the **ContactType** "Christmas List" to the **ContactList** ObservableCollection, Grid1 reflects the additional Contact however Grid2 does not reflect the **change** unless I rebind.

Anyway to Reflect the change in Grid2 to show the new **Contact** with the queried **ContactType**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid2 is actually binding to an IEnumerable(Of Contact) instead of an Observable Collection. That's why the change isn't reflected in Grid2. You need to cause your Linq query to reexecute using an event or INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I guess because i am using a Telerik Grid i could simply pass the filter the the FilterDescriptor function but just simply having Grid1 and Grid2 point to the same Collection and use the custom FilterDescriptor with the Grid2. Thanks for imparting knowledge on basic Linq architecture. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could be happening due to the deferred execution nature of LINQ query. The values are fetched only when, you start enumerating over the result set. That is why, you have to rebind the data source, to see the change. Try adding ToList(), method at the end of the query. For e.g.

```
Me.Grid2.ItemsSource = From s In ContactList Where s.ContactTypes.Any(Function(t) t.ContactTypeName = "Christmas List").ToList();
```

Comment: I did try this but with same results. I think the above answer is correct. I am looking into Rx to see if that is of any benefit. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. Using this library you can code like this:

```C#
Me.Grid2.ItemsSource = ContactList.Filtering(c => c.ContactTypes.ContainsComputing("Christmas List").Value);
```

Filtering extention method returns instance of [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) and reflects all the changes in the ContactList collection and ContactTypes collection. Writing the code above, I assumed contactContactTypes id ObservableCollection. If this is not so, then you can code:

```C#
Me.Grid2.ItemsSource = ContactList.Filtering(c => c.ContactTypes.Contains("Christmas List"));
```

In this case do not forget to add the implementation of the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface to Contact class, so that the result ObservableCollection reflects the change of contact.ContactTypes property.